# how to use vars_prompt only for group of hosts in inventory

Tags: ansible

I have below piece of code for vars prompt which is not working as expected.
I am trying to prompt user only when a specific group of hosts are being targeted during playbook execution using --limit, for all other hosts and groups prompt should not be displayed.

Below code prompts me irrespective of group I provide with --limit in ansible playbook call.

```
  vars_prompt:
   - name: playbook_password
     prompt: Please enter the playbook password
     private: 'yes'
     when: ('dbservers' in group_names)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vars_prompt` are Play-bound, so you can't apply any conditions to them.

You can use `pause` prompt workaround inside tasks:

```
- name: playbook_password task
  pause:
    prompt: Please enter the playbook password
  when: "'dbservers' in group_names"
  register: playbook_password_prompt

- name: set playbook_password fact
  set_fact:
    playbook_password: "{{ playbook_password_prompt.user_input }}"
  when: not playbook_password_prompt | skipped
```